# Windows workflow foundation. Should I use it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, workflow, workflow-foundation

I'm developing an application that I suspect is suitable for using workflow. (It's easy to visualise the physical workflow and tasks between different users.)

My question is what are the advantages to using this method, do you recommend that I go down this route. Is there a better approach.

I've heard mention of a hit in performance? Is this worth considering?

Finally, can anyone recommend a good book which is a good introduction to workflow?

UPDATE:
Brief overview of my solution - In basic terms it's a booking/event/diary system. A 'model' runs periodically which sets the'rating' of the users (H,M,L). Depending on the rating depends how often the 'adviser' visits the 'user'. The requirement is to automate the appointment system, so a 'tentative' appointment is made by the 'model'. 
The application will wait for a response confirming the appointment. Same situation with follow up meetings, etc. Hope this is enough to help. Basically control passes between the application and the user several times in arranging appointments

I'm thinking the event driven model would be the most appropriate here? Any input appreciated

Thanks

Comment: performance is _not_ good with WCF. If you have complex workflows and performance is secondary, go for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@Stuart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80385/stuart) if your Application has to follow some series of discrete steps (workflow states) you can definitely use Workflow Foundation (WF). You can keep the flow of the business process separate from the other logic of your application making it loosely coupled and thus easier to modify and enhance.

If you can simply decide using `if-else` constructs to decide if flow should move to next step (state) all the steps are traversed linearly then **`Sequential`** workflow will be good. If you can move from one step to another on occurrence of some event and can literally jump the steps based on the events then **`State Machine`** workflow is for you.

I've read *[Wrox- Professional Windows Workflow Foundation](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Windows-Workflow-Foundation.productCd-0470053860.html)* authored by Todd Kitta. It is a good book to start with. Definetly you can a wealth of information and examples at home of [Workflow Foundation at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328.aspx)

Comment: yeah, I can identify many workflow states, so I guess the big decision is whether it's state machine or sequential.

Comment: If you can elaborate a bit on the flow and the stages (states) then we will be more informed to offer a suggestion regarding type of Workflow you should choose.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot - thanks, I'll update my question , appreciate your input